# Batch Splitting a line of text into multiple lines, delimited by quotation space quotation

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

Thanks in Advance.

Using a DOS batch file, I am trying to read a text file that contains several full paths with quotes, separated by a space and write a new file containing one path per line.

For example, I want to turn this file:

```
"C:\path\filename.doc" "C:\path\filename.doc" "C:\path\filename.doc" "C:\path\filename.doc"
```

into this:

```
"C:\path\filename.doc"
"C:\path\filename.doc"
"C:\path\filename.doc"
"C:\path\filename.doc"
```

I have had some success using the wonderful [`repl.bat` (by dbenham)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat).

```
type "files.txt" | repl " " "\r\n" x l >"newfile.txt"
```

But when there are spaces in the filenames or path it breaks a new line in the middle of the path and wrecks it.

Ive tried passing  as the search variable into repl using the escape character `^`, i.e. `repl "^" ^""` and other ways with no joy.

At the end of the day, I simply need to move all the files into another directory, and so was going to then pass the resulting text file to another bulk delete batch file for processing, but perhaps there is a better way im missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a limitation in the length of the line, of around 8 KB.

Less than that and it will move the files to your new folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\folder\file.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do move "%%~b" "d:\existing\new\folder"
)
```

The code below should work to move all files in except the ones in the list.

It adds a hidden attribute to the files in the list, moves all the other files, then removes the hidden attributes again.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\folder\file.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do attrib +h "%%~b"
)
cd /d "c:\folder"
move *.* "d:\already\existing folder"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\folder\file.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do attrib -h "%%~b"
)
```

**Test code for Windows 2012 as mentioned in the comments**

```
@echo off
(echo "c:\widget1\test 1.txt" "2:\widget2\test 2.doc")>"file.txt"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do echo move "%%~b" "d:\existing\new\folder"
)
pause
```

Comment: Yes each line should be well under 8k, this works great., Thanks ! :)   I actually need to move all the files in the directory, EXECPT the ones in the file.txt, so I was going to move all these into a directory, delete the remaining, and then move these back in. Would it be possible to without the double handling ?

Comment: What is the error message on the screen?  Access Denied?

Comment: I think the same issue of longer lines over 8KB is stopping this from working as well. But the entire file.txt is 4KB according to its windows file properties, so it should be ok right ?

Comment: no, it doesnt run through any of the for loops, it doesnt throw any error message.

Comment: In the top batch script - put `echo` before `move` and add `pause` on a line at the bottom.  Run it and see what is on the screen.  It will help figure out the problem.  4KB filesize should be fine, if all the terms are quoted as you outlined.

Comment: That works testing with test folders under Win7 with spaces in directory names and filenames.  Ill try it at work next on our 2012 Server, where the paths are longer.  How many dos characters is 8KB anyway ?  I googled it, and it seems to be like 1 page of text !

Comment: adding the pause and echo confirms what I saw running it from a commandline with @echo off removed.  It runs the for command 'for /f "usebackq...  '  but it doesnt do anything after that. normally you see the iterations from the for loop running underneath

Comment: 8KB is around 8000 characters.  It would seem that `"c:\folder\file.txt"` on that machine is empty, in a different format (or missing) if there is no execution of the lines.

Comment: Your answer works on Windows 7, but Windows 2012 cant execute the for loop.  It just skips past it, like it doesnt run at all.

Comment: I mentioned to check the `"c:\folder\file.txt"` file.  I edited my answer above and added code for you to test in an empty folder in `Windows 2012` and I will be very surprised if it doesn't run and show you commands on the screen.

Comment: The source file was the problem. Its encoding was unicode, had to convert to Ascii first. Your test code worked, and pointed me towards the issue, which I fixed using the CSCRIPT batch file [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php#Unicode) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following batch file `split.bat` and call it redirecting the content of your text file into it and redirecting the output into another file like `split.bat < files.txt > newfiles.txt`:

```
@echo off
set /P INFILE=
call :SPLIT %INFILE%
exit /B

:SPLIT
shift
if "%~0"=="" exit /B
echo "%~0"
goto :SPLIT
```

If you do not provide an input file (`< files.txt`) the scripts prompts you for a space-separated list.
If no output file is given (`> newfiles.txt`), the created new-line-separated list is shown on screen.

Notice that this does not verify whether your input file fulfills the described formatting.

This method is **limited to a list length of 1021 bytes** (characters), everything after will be truncated!

Comment: This will fail if the original line is longer than 1021 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can guarantee that each file path is enclosed within double quotes, then you just need to tweak your REPL.BAT command a bit:

```
type "files.txt" | repl "(\q.*?\q) *" "$1\r\n" x >"newfile.txt"
```

But REPL.BAT has been superseded by [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - it has even more functionality, and a slightly different syntax.

A JREPL solution can be as simple as:

```
jrepl "\q.*?\q" $0 /x /jmatch /f file.txt /o newfile.txt
```

If you want, you can overwrite the original file with the result by specifying `-` as the output file.

```
jrepl "\q.*?\q" $0 /x /jmatch /f file.txt /o -
```

If each line in the original file is <8k, then the following pure batch script should work, and it is pretty simple:

```
@echo off
>newfile.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (files.txt) do for %%B in (%%A) do echo %%B
)
```

Comment: EDIT - I forgot the `\q` escape sequence requires the `/X` option.

Comment: I tried playing around with the \q and x options, but was missing the .*? as I didnt\don't understand how the selection applies. Cheers

Comment: My input files are going to be fairly long in some cases, more than 8KB on occasions But my testing is failing with sizes @ 866bytes, or 4KB as reported by windows, and it fails with the Jscript Error "JScript runtime error in Replace code: Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: However when it does runs with very short test examples, every character in the output has a space i n b e t w e e n  l i k e   t h i s .